# Is there a Visual Studio 2017 extension to allow automatic import generation in TypeScript modules?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have started learning ASP.NET Core 1.1 and Angular2 using an online course. The presentations are done in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), but I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. Everything works fine, except for one thing: auto imports generation in TypeScript.

This can be easily obtain in VS Code by using [Auto Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) or [TypeScript Hero](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero) extensions.

**Question: is there a way to obtain imports auto-generation in Visual Studio 2017?**

Comment: It can't be that hard

Comment: It is not hard, but I am intrigued that VS Code has something, VS 2017 seems to lack (for now).

Comment: VS Code has a lot of things that VS 2017 lacks. Quick fixes for imports are part of recent typescript releases and will work their way back to Visual Studio, but there will not be plugin parity. This is because it is easier to extend VS Code and because it can release faster.

Comment: Oh, that explains a lot. I will take VS Code for a spin, but at work I have VS + R# which is really useful in some scenarios. Unfortunately, R# is not intended and there are no plans for it in the near future ([source](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206010179-Is-there-any-plans-for-Resharper-to-support-VS-Code-)).

Comment: you don't have to choose I use both editors. R# has some special TypeScript behavior that can be useful but also can interfere with recently added features.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that this feature has been embedded within the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 - 15.2 (26430.14):

[image: Auto import Angular 2 classes]